# How to include & setup brian gladman aes with msvs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, aes, filepath

so I just found out about brian gladmans aes encryption/decryption support for c/c++ in my cryptography class today. My question is, after I downloaded the build for MSVS 2012 - how do I include the paths properly with my compiler so that when I use the calls, they will be recognized by the compiler?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project file in the solution pane, choose "Properties" option at the bottom.  Click on the small arrow to the left of "C/C++" to expand it, then click on "General".  Click on "Additional Include Directories", then click on the "..." button on the right side.  Now add the path to the include files to the modal dialog that's appeared.  Click "OK" when done.

Now that you've returned to the "Properties" dialog, click on the small arrow to the left of "Linker" to expand it, then click on "Input".  Click on "Additional Dependencies", then click on the "..." button on the right side.  Now add the path to the library you've built to the modal dialog that's appeared.  Click "OK" when done, then Click "OK" on the "Properties" dialog.